# R - Contour Map

Tags: r, lattice, contour

I have a contour plot, I am wondering is it possible to label the individual contour levels as well as the colours? (i.e. say the first pink contour is 0.2, second is 0.4 or whatever works).

Also, what is the argument for filling land as a solid color?

```
library(lattice)
contourplot(cor_Warra_SF_SST_SON, region=TRUE, at=seq(-1, 1, 0.2), 
labels=FALSE, row.values=lon_sst, column.values=lat_sst,
xlab='longitude', ylab='latitude')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include labels for the contour lines, simply set `labels = TRUE` (in place of the `labels=FALSE` that you are currently using).

`?contourplot` document the `labels` argument thusly:

> `labels:` typically a logical indicating whether contour lines should
>             be labelled, but other possibilities for more sophisticated
>             control exists.  Details are documented in the help page for
>             ‘panel.levelplot’, to which this argument is passed on
>             unchanged.  That help page also documents the ‘label.style’
>             argument, which affects how the labels are rendered.

To add filled polygons for the continents, I'd try using `mapplot()` from the `latticeExtra` package, adding it to the plot you're already produced using `layer()`, also from `latticeExtra`. (I can't get much more specific than that without having access to the data you are using.)

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to specify label region like (-1,-0.5) and (0.5,1)?

Comment: Have a look at the `at=` argument, documented in both `?contourplot` and `?panel.contourplot`. I'd try something like `at =c(-1, -.5, 0, .5, 1)` (Also don't be concerned that `at=` appears to be an argument to just `levelplot()`, rather than `contourplot()`: in fact, the same panel function is used for both, and they differ only in their default values.)  Good luck!